# Redirect function to reload the same page

Tags: php, redirect

I set up a message system and on my upload action script instead of sending the user to a success page I'm using Session flash to display a message on the same page.

The problem I'm having is getting the page to redirect back to the original page that has a query string attached to it like this send.php?st_id=11

Normally I simply do a redirect like this:

```
Session::flash('user-reply', '<h3>Your Reply has been submitted!</h3>');

Redirect::to('index.php');
```

How can I use the Redirect function to reload the same page with a query string attached to it? 
This is what I'm trying, but not working.

```
Redirect::to($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?'.$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
```

I was also told by someone not to use PHP_SELF ever, but to try `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`, but I can't seem to figure out how to get that working either.

If someone has a solution please let em know.

Here is my Redirect class:

```
<?php
class Redirect {
    public static function to($location = null) {

        if($location) {
            if(is_numeric($location)) {
                switch($location) {
                    case 404:
                        header('HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found');
                        include 'includes/errors/404.php';
                        exit();
                    break;
                }
            } else {
                header('Location: ' . $location);
                exit();
            }
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: what framework are you using?

Comment: I'm not using a framework @dave

Comment: then can you post the contents of your Redirect class so we can tell you how to use it?

Comment: `Redirect::to` isn't a standard php function.  Where is the redirect class coming from?

Comment: I built this off a tutorial from php academy

Comment: @dave FYI see my redirect class at the top

Comment: When I try `Redirect::to($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);` The info gets stored into my database table, but the page doesn't refresh and simply times out.

Comment: FYI you should separate concerns in your code - `$location` should never be both a URL and an error code.

Comment: @AlienWebguy thanks for the tip! I was just going off the tutorial, trying to learn. I should try a different tutorial next time =)

Answer (score 0):

Okay I got it to work: I ditched the `Redirect::to` and used the following:

```
header("Location: check-status.php?st_id=$st_id");
```

That worked. Thanks for taking time out to check this question out for me though.